# Getting an Aurora Serverless Cluster ARN in CloudFormation (Output)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I am having trouble retrieving the ARN for a new RDS Aurora Serverless cluster inside a CloudFormation template.

Can someone please advise on what reference the output value should be below?

```yaml
Resources:
  RDSCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      MasterUsername: someusername
      MasterUserPassword: somepass
      DatabaseName: mydb
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: '10.7'
      EnableHttpEndpoint: true
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: false
        MaxCapacity: 16
        MinCapacity: 2
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300

Outputs:
  RDSClusterARN:
    Description: RDS Cluster ARN
    Export:
      Name: RDSCluster
    Value:
      Ref: RDSCluster # Help! What should this value be?
```

The output I currently get:

```json
    {
        "OutputKey": "RDSClusterARN",
        "OutputValue": "t1-rdscluster-1i771l6x4amfg",
        "Description": "RDS Cluster ARN",
        "ExportName": "RDSCluster"
    },
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of current limitations of the AWS CloudFormation `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` resource, you have to construct its ARN by hand as follows (see also [Working with Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) in Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_Tagging.ARN.html))

```yaml
!Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:rds:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster:${RDSCluster}"
```